# Powershell - net use doesn't work with variables

Tags: powershell, variables, scripting, net-use, drive-mapping

I'm trying to get a script running that maps network drives at login. Generally, I use get-content with | convertfrom-stringdata to put my parameters (drive letter and path) in a hash.

My problem is the following:

```
net use /persistent:no $driveletter $networkpath
```

results with an error. When I replace $networkpath with the actual path (\\server\share\folder), it works.

Does anyone know what to do there? Help is greatly appreciated.
If any information is missing, I'll add it as soon as I can!

Greetings,

Blaargh

**EDIT: more code for better understanding of problem**

```
$hash = get-content C:\temp\file.txt | convertfrom-stringdata
    foreach ($keys in $hash.keys) {
    $hashtwo = $hash.$keys -split ("=")
    net use /persistent:no $hashtwo[1] $hashtwo[0]
}
```

My textfile looks like this:
`key = \\\\server\\share\\folder =G:`

Comment: Don't really see a problem with it on the surface. Are you sure `$networkpath` contains what you think it does? Does it contain spaces? If you `echo "~$networkpath~"` what do you get?

Comment: `$driveletter = "x:"
`$networkpath = "\\server\share"`
`net use /persistent:no $driveletter $networkpath` works fine for me as well

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work like that. Are the quotes neccessary?
Let me put in some more code here to get you an idea of where the problem could be.

Comment: When echoing $networkpath or $driveletter, it always comes up with the right content by the way

Comment: @blaargh Add `Write-Host "'$($hashtwo[1])' '$($hashtwo[0])'"` to be sure, that variables does not have extra space somewhere.

Comment: @PetSerAl HUGE thanks to you. There was a space behind the path, removing it made the problem disappear. I owe you mate!

Comment: I copied your answer and gave you the credit, I'm new on this board and hope I did it right. If not, please tell me how to correctly mark your comment as an answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: @blaargh I does not really care much about abstract internet points, feel free to just accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PetSerAl found the solution:

@blaargh Add Write-Host "'$($hashtwo[1])' '$($hashtwo[0])'" to be sure, that variables does not have extra space somewhere.